# Why can't I get Thymeleaf to work on Script tags

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a simple Spring Boot application and I am trying to add Thymeleaf. The basic structure of my app is available [here](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/d86c6ac489f7c77aa9eadcc273ed445c).

Basically when I try to render the following in the template...

```
<h1>[[${key}]]</h1>
```

It works perfect! However, when I try...

```
<script src="https://my.api.com/api/js?key=${key}" />
```

The `${key}` is not getting replaced. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Thymeleaf to resolve attributes, you have to prefix them with `th:`.

```
<script th:src="|https://my.api.com/api/js?key=${key}|" />
```

or

```
<script th:src="@{https://my.api.com/api/js(key=${key})}" />
```